# MySQL two table join - get result according to status - did not work

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get number of pending items SUM by joining two tables, which are delivery and delivery_history.

delivery_history table has status. For example one order can have many status such as Pending, Invoiced.

**delivery**

```
id | items
-----------
10 | 12
11 | 10
13 | 20
```

**delivery_history**

```
id | delivery_id | status 
---------------------
1    10         Pending
2    10         Invoiced - this is the current status of delivery id 10
3    11         Pending  - this is the current status of delivery id 11
4    13         Pending  - this is the current status of delivery id 13
```

I want to get sum of the items of all pending orders. For that I wrote following query but it did not work and gave me an errors. Could someone please look into this.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as latest_status = "Pending"' at line 12

```
  SELECT SUM(delivery.items) AS pending_count
    FROM delivery 
    JOIN delivery_history ON delivery_history.delivery_id = delivery.id
    WHERE delivery.deleted="0"  
    AND
    (select dh.delivery_status
    from delivery_history dh
    where dh.delivery_id = delivery.id
    order by dh.id desc
    limit 1
    ) 
    as latest_status = "Pending"
```

Comment: If it gave you an error message it is polite if you share that message in full with us

Comment: @RiggsFolly ,sorry for the mistake, this is the error msg, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as status = "Pending"' at line 12

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following query:

```
 SELECT SUM(delivery.items) AS pending_count
    FROM delivery 
    JOIN delivery_history ON delivery_history.delivery_id = delivery.id 
        AND delivery_history.status='Pending'
    WHERE delivery.deleted="0"  
    group by delivery_history.delivery_id
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the ans, all deliveries has pending status, but after product is delivered, that status will be changed to invoiced. then i don't want to get count of invoiced orders

Answer (score 0):

This following query should also work if i understand well :

```
SELECT SUM(d.items)
FROM delivery d JOIN (
     SELECT dh1.* FROM delivery_history dh1
     JOIN (
          SELECT delivery_id, MAX(id) as dhid 
          FROM delivery_history GROUP BY delivery_id
     ) dh2 ON dh1.id = dh2.dhid
     WHERE status = "Pending"
) dhp ON d.id = dhp.delivery_id
```